# Could be "Directory index forbidden by Options directive" the cause for "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects"?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache2

I am trying to setup a project in my local environment so I am able to work on it. PHP 5.3.3 is being used and Apache 2.2.15 with CodeIgniter 2.3.1 (PHP and CI version are not relevant here but is just FYI in case is needed).

I have setup a VH as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/document_api/public"
    ServerName document.api.localhost    
    <Directory "/var/www/html/document_api/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

And the project `/var/www/html/document_api/public/.htaccess` file is as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Rule 2: IF a file exists when .php is added, then rewrite URL by adding .php
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-_Za-z]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

As soon as I try to hit the URL for `document.api.localhost:8080` I got the following errors:

```
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:50 2018] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/document_api/public/
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:50 2018] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] File does not exist: /var/www/error
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:51 2018] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://document.api.localhost:8080/
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:51 2018] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 10.0.2.2] r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/favicon.ico, referer: http://document.api.localhost:8080/
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:51 2018] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 10.0.2.2] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/favicon.ico, referer: http://document.api.localhost:8080/
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:51 2018] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 10.0.2.2] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/favicon.ico, referer: http://document.api.localhost:8080/
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:51 2018] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 10.0.2.2] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/favicon.ico, referer: http://document.api.localhost:8080/
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:51 2018] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 10.0.2.2] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/favicon.ico, referer: http://document.api.localhost:8080/ [Mon Jan 22 17:25:51 2018] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 10.0.2.2] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/favicon.ico, referer: http://document.api.localhost:8080/
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:51 2018] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 10.0.2.2] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/favicon.ico, referer: http://document.api.localhost:8080/
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:51 2018] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 10.0.2.2] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/favicon.ico, referer: http://document.api.localhost:8080/
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:51 2018] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 10.0.2.2] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/favicon.ico, referer: http://document.api.localhost:8080/
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:51 2018] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 10.0.2.2] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/favicon.ico, referer: http://document.api.localhost:8080/
[Mon Jan 22 17:25:51 2018] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 10.0.2.2] redirected from r->uri = /favicon.ico, referer: http://document.api.localhost:8080/
```

Am I missing something here? What's is wrong in this setup?

Comment: It's not the directory index request that causes the endless redirect, it's a favicon.ico request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your log file. First, there is the directory index forbidden, which is caused by

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The requested path is clearly a directory, it's the `DocumentRoot` directory. So the rule redirecting to PHP is skipped. And you probably don't have `index.php` as your `DirectoryIndex` and directory listing is forbidden ([documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings)).

The second problem, endless redirect, is caused by another request, this time the browser requesting `favicon.ico`. The file doesn't exist and is rewritten to `index.php/favicon.ico`, but no such file nor folder exists, it's rewritten to `index.php/index.php/favicon.ico` and so on.

You should probably skip redirecting to `index.php/something` and change it to GET parameters, I don't see any reason why you try to redirect it this way. `/index.php?path=something` would make more sense.